# Javascript: Hover over Issues & How can I structure the html efficiently?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a Javascript that triggers upon a person interacting an image, but I have some difficulty tackling the issues that I'm having. Please take a look :)

**Heres what the Javascript written is suppose to do:**
**1)** When person opens page, all they see are a collection of images.
**2)** When the cursor / mouse is hovered over the image **2a)** `info` text `fadesIn` on the bottom and right (`.rotate`) of the image, **2b)** the `grayscale` effect lowers from `100%` to `10%`, and **2c)** `.detail` `fadesIn` at a fixed position on the bottom right corner of the page.
**3)** All images are associated with a number. That number is then used so that each image can have its own content & text / `position:` / `color:` / etc.

**And here are the problems I'm facing with:**
**1)** When an image that has its position set as `bottom`, it moves up when a curser hovers over it.
**2)** Upon hovering, when the cursor hovers over the images text, it for some reason repeatedly `fadesIn` and `fadesOut`.
**3)** How can I set the `.detail` to be positioned to the `bottom` `right` of the page for all images?
**4)** How can the image number (set as `.rotate`) placed outside of the image and be vertically centered from the images height?

Here is a jsfiddle for visual / functionality reference: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/53bv6hyu/7/)

Thank you in advance!

**JS**

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();

$('.show').mouseover(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').hover();
    $('.info' + $(this).attr('target')).fadeIn();
});

$('.show').mouseout(function () {
    $('.targetDiv').fadeOut();
    $('.info' + $(this).attr('target')).fadeOut();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="show" id="subject01" target="01">
    <div class="frontpage-img-wrap">
        <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/fw3tpc.jpg" width="250" height="auto" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="targetDiv info01">
         <h2>Name</h2>

         <h4>Text</h4>

        <p class="rotate">Image Number</p>
        <p class="detail">Image Detail
            <br/>Detail
            <br/>More Detail.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END 01 -->
<div class="show" id="subject02" target="02">
    <div class="frontpage-img-wrap">
        <img src="http://i59.tinypic.com/ogeybn.jpg" width="150" height="auto" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="targetDiv info02">
         <h2>Name</h2>

         <h4>Text</h4>

        <p class="rotate">Image Number</p>
        <p class="detail">Image Detail
            <br/>Detail
            <br/>More Detail.</p>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END 02 -->
```

**CSS**

```
*, html, body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, form, label, fieldset, input, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
fieldset, img {
    border:0
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal
}
a img {
    border:none
}
p, li h2, body, h4, h4 a {
    font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
h2 {
    font-family:"Apercu Bold", sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
}
h4 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
}
a {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: none;
}
header a:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.frontpage-img-wrap, .img-placeholder, .image-wrapper-inner {
    margin: 0 0 18px;
}
.entry {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
}
.frontpage-img-wrap {
    position: relative;
}
.frontpage-img-wrap img {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
}
.rotate {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    position: absolute;
    right: -45px;
    top:50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 18px;
    font-family: monospace;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
}
.frontpage-img-wrap {
    display:block;
}
#subject01 {
    left: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    position: fixed;
}
#subject02 {
    right: 50px;
    bottom: 100px;
    position: fixed;
}
h6 {
    position: fixed;
    top:40%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve all your issues with CSS only [JSBin here](http://jsbin.com/vinote/1/edit?output)

**New CSS**

```
   .rotate {
      display:block;
      position:absolute;
      font-size: 12px;
      line-height: 18px;
      font-family: monospace;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      margin: 0;
      text-align: center;
      top:45%;
      left:95%;
      height:18px;
      visibility: hidden;
      opacity:0;
      -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
      -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
      transition: all 250ms linear; 

      transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
      filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  }
  .targetDiv { 
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 250ms linear;
    transition: all 250ms linear; 
  }

  .show:hover .targetDiv {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
  }  
  .show:hover .rotate {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity:1;
  }
```

**HTML Changes**

- Take `<p class="rotate"> ... </p>` out of `targetDiv` and move it into `frontpage-img-wrap`

**Notes**

- `position:absolute;width:100%` solves the bottom positioned div from jumping up on hover
- fade in/out effects are done with transition `opacity` and `visibility`
- easier to debug since you can now for the `:hover` state in developer tools
- The position of rotate is inexact - you may need to calculate image height with JS, then set the rotate div's HEIGHT as the images width

Comment: Wow, you sir are amazing. You've completely simplified everything! Let alone I was really hoping I can avoid Javascript.

I'm wondering, even though the cursor leaves the image, is it possible that the detail maintain visible until the cursor hovers over a different image? Also, is it possible to delay the text fadeOut (for example, upon the cursor hovers away from the image, it'll take 2s for the text to fadeOut)? 

Thank you so much in advance, really. You rock.

Comment: You might need some JS for the 1st question, but to delay you just add `transition-delay: 2s;` to `.show:hover`

Comment: EDIT: I've written this but it doesn't seem to be working. can you take a quick look?

`$(".targetDiv").show(function() {
    $(this).hover('.fadeoutdelay').show();
}, function() );`

Comment: Ah I see, if I were to want that delay only on `.featuredetail`, how might I do that? I tried modifying the java, but it didn't work—is that because its within show?

Comment: The JS in my bin isnt doing anything, i just forgot to take it out. The change was with CSS

Comment: Crap, I'm sorry I think there was a slight miscommunication--I meant `.featuredetail`, not `.rotate`. When I flipped and replaced some of the delay commands, classes like rotate didn't show up and the delay effect didn't work on anything. Otherwise the delay is working great!

Answer (score 1):

#### Addressing only your fadeIn/Out issues:

I'd really suggest using pure CSS for this. The JS just complicates it:

```
.targetDiv { opacity: 0; transition: opacity 0.5s linear; }

.frontpage-img-wrap:hover + .targetDiv { opacity: 1; }
```

So don't `hide()` (creates `display: none;`) your text at all, but just drop opacity to 0, set a transition (for that nice fade effect... make sure to use vendor prefixes with `transition`), then raise opacity to 1 whenever `.frontpage-img-wrap` is hovered.

#### Edit

As far as your bottom-aligned elements: it is because of the `$('.targetDiv').hide();` (translated `display: none;`) that is pops up when hovered... it needs to maintain size. Doing my CSS trick of just turning off the opacity will let the text keep its size. But if you must do it with JS, you need to set the size of the whole `.show` element so it doesn't resize on hover.

Comment: Oh my god, I was actually really hoping I could avoid Java, but you've absolutely nailed it!

As for the detail element, is there any way when the cursor is off the image, the text stays visible until the cursor lands on a different image?

Comment: Hmm, well that will definitely be a javascript thing. I would assign a "selected" class to the element you hover first (style that class with `opacity: 1`), then when you hover another element, clear all elements with that "selected" class and put it on the new image. That make any sense? (BTW: `JavaSCRIPT` and `Java` are two vastly different things)